# Rails will not install on my Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, macos, ruby-on-rails-3

Whenever I attempt to install Rails on my Mac it works fine but immediately after when I attempt to see what version of Rails I have, the terminal says that I do not have Rails installed.

Here's what I see in my terminal:

```
admins-MBP-5:~ Programming$ sudo gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
admins-MBP-5:~ Programming$ rails --version
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.
```

These lines tell that you haven't install XCode, it's necessary to many console utilities.

Also, you install your gems with sudo - it can cause several problems with privileges later. I recommend you to use [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) to manage ruby installations, it will save you from a lot of problems in future.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to read your error messages is something that will help you a lot in the future.

```
try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
```

That text is in your own error messages, give it a shot. Once you have Xcode installed, try installing Rails again.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, "it works fine"??? No, it doesn't, at all - the install is  failing because current Rails requires the nokogiri gem.

Read and follow the directions starting from 'The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing' ...