# How to FIX Zlib missing error on OSX 10.14?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zlib

I found this "Zlib missing" continously when installing gems for Rails on Ruby, please let me know a solution :

```
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.2
Installing nokogiri 1.10.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.2/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.2/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20190407-34092-u44l37.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts  -I /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libxml2... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I also re-installed OSX 10.14 SDK header but didn't work.

Comment: Depending on your OS setup you can try `brew install zlib`. Alternatively it could be that you haven't installed the command line tools - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304531/rails-will-not-install-on-my-mac but it seems that you have done that from the error message. Or it could be that the version of libxml on your system is too new.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I have to manually download zlib from its site and then install it myself to make it work.

Extract the package then install as instruction :

```
./Configure
make
make install
```